# Пора была прояснить вопрос про "Пора было"

Tags: фразеология

Ср. "Пора было кормить глокую куздру", "Пора была кормить глокую куздру".
Мне лично более импонирует словосочетание "Пора была" в любых вариантах. Потому что "связь времён" можно проверить с помощью: "Пришла пора". А вот "Пришло пора" пока ещё никто не говорит (наверное).
Но, может быть, я не прав?
Знаю, что некоторые языковеды даже научную базу подводят под сочетание "пора было". Даже и у меня самого такое порой выскакивает! Особенно в устной речи.

Но стоит ли допускать варваризацию языка или лучше каждый раз поправлять человека, говорящего "пора было"? (И самого себя тоже :) )

Comment: Мне кажется, чаще говорят в другом порядке: "пора было". Это звучит естественнее. Но насколько это вообще нормальное выражение, лучше других послушать. "Была пора" в Вашем примере уж совсем странно звучит. Вот "пришла пора" — другое дело.

Comment: Поторопился! :) Конечно! Спасибо за поправку! Рассеянность - это просто бич! Исправлю, с вашего позволения.

Answer (score 1):

1) Правилен только один вариант: **Пора было кормить** глокую куздру.

Из словаря: ПОРА в функц. сказ. О наступлении времени, срока для чего-л. П. спать.  П. обедать.

Предложение безличное, сказуемое составное глагольное, вспомогательная часть выражена сущ. "пора" со связкой "было" (связка нужна для выражения времени и модальности, в настоящем времени - нулевая связка).

2) Двусоставные предложения (пора - подлежащее, была - сказуемое). Из словаря: ПОРА, чего, какая. Время, период; какой-л. определённый момент, период для чего-л. Сенокосная, страдная п. П. половодья. П. школьных каникул. Утренняя, поздняя п. Весенняя, зимняя п.

Примеры: «Была пора: наш праздник молодой сиял, шумел и розами венчался…». Также: Тогда почему-то была пора (какая?) коллекционирования ― все что-нибудь собирали. Или: Была сенокосная пора.

Comment: "Правилен только один вариант..."   Подскажите пожалуйста, это из какого-то источника? (кроме словаря) Мнения, кажется, разделились.

Comment: Я думаю, что только первый вариант верен, так как "пора" в безличном предложении приобретает оттенок  необходимости, например: пора идти - это  надо идти. Соответственно, имеет местосущественная разница между предикативной формой  "пора было" и предметным значением сущ. "была пора". А источник - это общая грамматика, я думаю, что мы имеем дело с двумя разными грамматическими конструкциями.

Answer (score 0):

**Пора было кормить** - **сказуемое,** *пора* - слово категории состояния, предикативное наречие; предложение безличное. **Пора была кормить** - **подлежащее и сказуемое**, *пора* - существительное, предложение двусоставное.

Оба варианта возможны, ошибок нет, хотя второй вариант выглядит несколько надуманным. *Пора было* - корректное выражение, здесь *пора* - предикативное наречие.

Comment: Спасибо. Только речь не об этом. Речь идёт о правомерности употребления искажённых форм. Искажённых с течением времени.  Надеюсь, нет возражений, что изначальная форма этого выражения - "Пора была"?" Пора было" - это варваризм 20-го века, перешедший в степень устойчивого выражения.

Comment: Понятны ваши сомнения, но в ответе я пыталась показать, что оба варианта возможны, и объяснила почему. Извините, что не написала этого. Дополню ответ.